# How to update multiple SQL records with same condition

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
id  |  attributeId | value
--------------------------
 1  |     1        |   abc
 2  |     1        |   def
```

I want to update this table where "attributeId = 1" with these values {"123", "456", "789"} so the table will look like this:

```
id  |  attributeId | value
--------------------------
 1  |     1        |   123
 2  |     1        |   456
 3  |     1        |   789
```

My idea is to delete all the old records and then add new records but I think there are more better method to do this. Is there any better way?

Comment: do you need to update only three records or are there any more records to update?

Comment: @Riyana there can be 1,2,3 or more records. The overall target is to update the table to have exactly same amount and values of the new input.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following:

1. `Alter table Your_Table DROP COLUMN VALUE`
2. `CREATE TABLE TEMP (ID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(3));`
3. `INSERT INTO TMP VALUES (1, '123'), (1,  '456'), (1, '789');`
4. `SELECT A.*, B.VALUE INTO NEW_TABLE FROM Your_Table a join TMP b on a.id = b.id;`

The new_table will have your requested structure.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to replace the table, then just delete all the rows and insert new values:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t (id, attributeId, value)
    values (1, 1, 123), 
           (2, 1, 456), 
           (3, 1, 789);
```

If you don't want the original rows that are not in the new data, I would not bother trying to figure out the differences between the tables.  The `truncate` should be pretty fast and bulk updates are usually faster than update some records and insert some others.